# Showing unknown SRS (native SRS) when importing shapefile into GeoServer

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geoserver, shapefile

I am facing a problem on an unknown SRS when I am importing a shapefile into GeoServer. I am trying to import a shapefile into GeoServer but when I am publishing the shapefile, it is giving the unknown SRS in Native SRS on GeoServer. I am giving the link of screenshot of issue: ( http://mindcrewgis.com/screensho_error/shape_file.png)

Then after I set the SRS (900913) and publish the layer, I am getting another error on the layer preview when I click on any feature on the layer. It is giving an error like:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: An exception occurred while parsing WKB data org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: An exception occurred while parsing WKB data An exception occurred while parsing WKB data null

And it does not give any feature information.
The screenshot is here: http://mindcrewgis.com/screensho_error/feature_error.png

But the same shapefile works fine on QGIS on my Desktop.
Please give me the solution to the above problem.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the SRS as 3857? I'm not sure that 900913 is supported in GeoServer. In any case, it's a somewhat deprecated code now since the projection has been officially recognised with an EPSG code.

Answer (score 1):

Your first error shows that your shapefile, possibly, is in one of these cases:

- has no prj associated;
- an EPSG code cannot be found;
- has no CRS or it's unknown to GeoServer.

(See [CRS handling](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/advanced/crshandling/configurecrs.html))

The second error, shows also that, inside the shapefile, GeoServer sees null data.

Therefore, I suggest you to load the shapefile in QGIS, and:

- to perform a topology checking (`Vector > Topology Checker`), assuring yourself you have no invalid geometries;
- to check the geometry validity from `Vector > Geometry Tools`);

Eventually, save the new `clean` shapefile, using a valid CRS, and try to load it again in GeoServer.